# Scroll if element is longer than parent, center if it's shorter with CSS only?

Tags: css

I'm in a situation where a certain element can have very short or very long content without me having any way to know which is going to be the case.

The way I would like to handle this is that if the element is shorter than its parent, I'd like the element to be centered horizontally and vertically within the parent; if the element is longer, I'd like it to be naturally positioned within the parent and to be able to scroll the parent (not the element itself) to see the content out of view. Here's a quick image I made to illustrate the case:

[image]

Is there anyway that I can do this with CSS only? I'll take any solution that is compatible with IE11.

**What I tried**

So far I tried centering the element within the parent with flexbox and adding `overflow: scroll` to the parent, but when the content is longer than the parent it still gets centered and gets cut both on top and at the bottom...

```
#parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Try a container with scroll auto and a wrapper with min height 100% and contents centered vertically. Post what you get and we can help troubleshoot

Comment: Yes indeed it is possible. Please share whatever you tried so far.

Comment: @divy3993 Hi, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ok i am giving you a solution below.

Comment: @grazianodev, added the solution below, with updated reason. Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found a solution myself inspired by [this article](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/):

```
#parent {
    overflow-y: auto; 
    text-align: center; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    // Any padding-bottom here won't work in IE11
}

#parent:before {
    content: ''; 
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#child {
    text-align: left; 
    white-space: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    // Any padding-bottom here WILL work, even in IE11
}
```

This works just like intended, centering the child element within the parent when it's shorter, and causing the parent element to scroll if the child is longer. This is a plus, since if the child is narrower than the parent the scrollbar will still appear on the side of the parent.

Haven't tested it yet in all browsers, but I don't see why it wouldn't work since the 2011 article I linked above mentions the technique is supported by all browsers, including IE8+. I will test it though and update the answer in case I discover it's incompatible with any.

**+++ UPDATE +++**

I've tested this technique in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE11 and Ms Edge. It works everywhere. Like it was pointed out in the comments below, if you add any `padding-bottom` on the parent in IE11 it won't be rendered, but that can easily be fixed by transfering it to the child element if you can do that. Thankfully, I could!

Comment: Yes this would be great, but you will have to remove some space that, `#child:before { }` would create on left, besides `#child` element. https://codepen.io/divy3993/pen/PEKEpq

Comment: Also there would be some issues in even IE8+ browsers. Like in above shared codepen URL you might see that in IE 11 it isn't showing space below, created using padding.

Comment: I usually resolve that extra space that comes with `display: inline-block` by setting `font-size: 0` on the parent and then setting the desired font-size on the child element. I find it a better solution than using `margin-left`. As to IE, like I said I haven't tested it yet, but all-round this is the solution I was looking for. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; } body { margin: 0; background: #ddd; }
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  height: 80vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 5%;
  background: white;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center; /*Horizontally centers child in this case*/
}
.child {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 15px;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  /* width: 100%;  you could give full width as well */ 
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Update

**What you needed to solve?**

**Ans:** You needed was to give your `child` maximum height limit, `max-height:100%`, so that it won't get cut out at top and bottom.

Also you need to give the child `overflow: auto` no need for parent. Not `overflow: scroll`, as we don't need scroll tracks for child that doesn't need scrolls.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/divy3993/pen/MrvObw) link to play around

---

Hope this helped you!

Feel free to ask, if any queries. :)

Comment: Very clean answer +1 for using flexbox.

Comment: Really, Thank you! :)

Comment: This looks nice but like I said in the question I need to scroll the parent, not the child.

Comment: The child would unable to know the actual height that content needs, so `overflow:auto` helps it to scroll when needed. So if you want your parent to scroll, again child must be given exact height that content needs, not possible in such a way, using CSS. Alternative option would the answer you posted.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is a late reply but IMHO inline-block solution is a bit dirty

so here is my solution using flex box + extra div wrapper
https://jsfiddle.net/good/gyst4ufm

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  color: #333;
}
.box{
  resize: both; /* make boxes resizable */
  overflow: hidden; 
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.container{ 
  width: 500px; 
  height: 500px; 
  background: #333; 
  border: solid #333 1px;  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;  
  overflow: hidden; 
}
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.content{ 
  width: 400px; 
  height: 400px; 
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;   
  overflow: hidden;   
  margin: 0 auto;  
  max-width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box container">
   <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="box content">
          <p> to test layout you can resize both
          content box (white area) and its container (black area)</p>
          <p>- maximum content width is 90% of container</p>
          <p>- if the content is smaller than conainert, it is centered horizontally and verticaly</p>
          <p>- if the content is higher than container, use vertical scroll on container</p> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```